# Is it possible in v1 and v2 signature schemes use two different keys?

Tags: android, apk

There is new (v2) signature scheme of APK file. I can not understand from [doc](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v2) is it possible to use two different keys? If yes, how? Android Studio shows two options for one key. Is this limitation of method or Studio?

Is there any documentation how to make v2 signature manually (I mean from command line step by step)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide parameters for multiple signers/keys to `apksigner` by delimiting signers using `--next-signer`. For example:

```
apksigner sign --ks release.jks --next-signer --ks magic.jks app.apk
```

See `apksigner sign` for more details. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/apksig/+/master/src/apksigner/java/com/android/apksigner/help_sign.txt#168 and https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner.html